# proper way of downloading large files in php

Tags: php

Am using this code to download files of about 5mb and is working great.

Now when I use it to download files of about 10g and above. it will either freeze the browser or causes memory issue. I think the best way will be to read the files in bytes. something like the code below.

```
$chunk = 1 * 1024 * 1024 // 1m 
while (!feof($stream)) {
fwrite(fread($stream, $chunk));
}
```

**My questions** is please what is the best way. can someone help me with the integration of above code with the one below. Any possible solution will be appreciated. Thanks

**Here is the working code for small file download**

```
$output_filename = 'output10g.zip';
$host = "http://localhost/test/10g_file.zip"; //source 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$stream = fopen("download/$output_filename", 'wb');
fwrite($stream, $result);
fclose($stream);
```

Comment: If you're downloading a large file, and you don't send it back to the browser I would do the download during the HTTP request, but instead run it as a separate script. That way the HTTP response can immediately return while the download happens in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fread()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) for handling large files.

```
$download_file = 'movie.mp4';

$chunk = 1024; // 1024 kb/s

if (file_exists($download_file) && is_file($download_file)) {
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($download_file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename=' . $download_file);

    $file = fopen($download_file, 'r');

    while(!feof($file)) {
        print fread($file, round($chunk * 1024));
        flush();
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

Tested on 2.5GB of MPEG-4 file.

**Do not forget to set** `max_execution_time = 0` **in your** `php.ini` **file.**